# mistake on Serialization of java

Tags: java, serialization

I want to serialize a class using `ByteArrayOutputStream` of java:

```
public void serializ(UniqueTag m) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutput);
            stream.writeObject(m);

        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
        byteOutput.flush();
        byteOutput.close();    
    }
```

**A class want to serialize :**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class UniqueTag implements Comparable<UniqueTag>, Serializable {
    public final static UniqueTag MIN = new UniqueTag(Integer.MIN_VALUE,
            Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    public final static UniqueTag MAX = new UniqueTag(Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    private final int replicaId;
    private final int counter;

    public static UniqueTagGenerator createGenerator() {
        return new UniqueTagGenerator() {
            int currentStamp;

            @Override
            public UniqueTag nextTag(final int replicaId) {
                return new UniqueTag(replicaId, currentStamp++);
            }
        };
    }

    public UniqueTag(final int replicaId, final int counter) {
        this.replicaId = replicaId;
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public int getReplicaId() {
        return replicaId;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(UniqueTag o) {
        if (replicaId != o.replicaId) {
            return replicaId - o.replicaId;
        }
        return counter - o.counter;
    }

    public UniqueTag clone() {
        return new UniqueTag(replicaId, counter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof UniqueTag))
            return false;
        final UniqueTag other = (UniqueTag) obj;
        return counter == other.counter && replicaId == other.replicaId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + replicaId + "," + counter + ")";
    }
}
```

**I have this error :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: jbenchmarker.treedoc.UniqueTag$1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
```

Please where is a problem ? i serialize a class but it displays to me an error ! :(

Comment: Could you please provide an SSCCE reproducing the problem (you're not far from an SSCCE anyway), because when I try to make one, everything serializes fine. Make sure you don't have an old version of the class in the classpath.

Comment: It does indeed look as if you are trying to serialize the anonymous inner class rather than UniqueTag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's complaining that an anonymous inner class is causing the problem, and you only have one anonymous inner class, so I believe that you can solve the problem by making `UniqueTagGenerator` implement `Serializable`.

I'm not entirely certain *why* this exception is being thrown, as an instance of `UniqueTag` should not hold any reference to the generator that created it. I suspect there's some needless chasing of class references going on (or you aren't showing the exact code).

Another way to fix it -- better, IMO -- is to separate out the tag generator implementation from `UniqueTag`. Either create a separate class, or add the factory method to `UniqueTagGenerator`.

Answer (score 2):

Your class should have an accessible no-arg constructor. Also your final fields wont be initialized. Have a look at the documentation for serializable, that might help.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: The no-arg constructor requirement is only required if you're extending a class that isn't `Serializable`, and I have no idea where you're getting "final fields" assertion. Could you clarify where you see that? I've serialized classes with final fields with no problem.

Comment: You are right that applies to non serializable classes sorry about that.